# how do I write a stored procedure where an input parameter gives back a result set?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've read through articles and other posts regarding cursors so I've tried to write one but I've either not written it correctly or am trying to use the stored procedure incorrectly. Below is my stored procedure that compiled okay.

Basically, I would like to be able to give it an invoice number and have it give me the row that corresponds to it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_invoices_info
(
invoice_id_param IN invoices.invoice_id%TYPE,
p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_recordset FOR
SELECT invoice_number,vendor_name,invoice_date,invoice_total,terms_id,invoice_due_date 
FROM invoices I INNER JOIN vendors v on I.vendor_id = V.vendor_id
where invoice_id = invoice_id_param;
END get_invoices_info;
/
```

The below is what I tried to get a output result but received "wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
p_recordset sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
get_invoices_info(10, p_recordset);
dbms_output.put_line(p_recordset);
END;
```

Would anyone be able to help please? Thank you.

Comment: read this http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php

Comment: From where you want to call it from your front end or u just want to run it from backend.

Comment: Assuming it is all correct, just within Oracle 11g to ensure it is working.

Comment: Exhausted: That's actually one of the things I read to get the above...thanks for the link though.

Comment: This is not giving you back a result set; it's giving you an open pointer to a result set, you then have to go fetch it yourself.